# chrome extension JS page load Chrome Tabs issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I currently have a simple Chrome extension that injects CSS for a specific page. I want to add user options.. which I have gotten as far as adding a checkbox that saves its value.

the problem is, i am trying to run JS on the page load, but the chrome.tabs is erroring..

1st i tried this:
alert('hi');

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({ProPicDisplay: true}, function(items) {
        alert(items.ProPicDisplay);
        chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function(tabs) { 
             alert('ho');
             });
});
```

which, i get the 1st and 2nd alert, not the third. no error

so then i tried:

```
alert('hi');

chrome.storage.sync.get({ProPicDisplay: true}, function(items) {
        alert(items.ProPicDisplay);

});

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function(tabs) { 
             alert('ho');
});
```

and again I get the 1st and 2nd alert, but errors on chrome.tabs.query

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

in my manifest I have:

Permissions (prob more than needed, but was testing):

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "activeTab", 
    "storage", 
    "declarativeContent",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://*/", 
    "https://*/" ],
```

and:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
      "matches":    ["*://gamdom.com/*"],
      "css":        ["gam.css"],
      "js":                 ["load.js"]

   }
```

so, the goal is to run this:

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabs[i].id,{code: ".chat_user_prof {display: " + disp + " !important;}"});
```

when the page loads..(but, it also errors)

also tried this but the alert says 0 for the classes?? lol

```
window.addEventListener ("load", pageFullyLoaded);

function pageFullyLoaded () {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({ProPicDisplay: true}, function(items) {
        var disp = 'none';
        if (items.ProPicDisplay) {
            disp = 'inline';
        }
        var cup = document.getElementsByClassName("chat_user_prof");
        alert(cup.length);
        cup.style.display = 'none';
});
}
```

EDIT:
if I use:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', pageFullyLoaded);
```

it doesnt trigger.. so the load.js is not seeing the page..? how do I get it to see the page/doc?

Comment: The error means `chrome.tabs` is undefined. It's because you can't use chrome.tabs in a content script. You can do it in a background script.

Comment: doesnt work as a background page either.. that loads when the extension is loaded. I need it when the webpage is loaded...

Comment: chrome.tabs works in the background page. If it doesn't for you then you're doing something wrong. You probably need chrome.tabs.onUpdated listener. Make sure you understand the [architecture of extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and inspect some simple [official demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! lol thats exactly what was missing!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the reply above.. i was missing/needed chrome.tabs.onUpdate !!!